# arrangement of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

How to know the arrangement of a basis?

e.g:

> Let **V** be the span of sin*x* and cos*x* in C∞, T(f)= 3f + 2f'- f'', T: V → V,
>   1. Find B-matrix, 2. Is T an isomorphism?

Solving this question, I have to find the Basis first, but I don't know which basis is correct, because the arrangement do have impact on the answer.

> Basis {sin*x*, cos*x*}, or Basis {cos*x*, sin*x*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis is a set, and a set is an unordered list. So long as bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ have the same elements, the bases are the same.

I should add that the choice of basis order will affect the matrix, but only up to a permutation.

Comment: But the result of matrix-B is different, doesn't it matter?

Comment: Yes and no. Columns will be the same but in a different order.

Comment: You mean the 2 B-matrices are both correct?

Comment: Yes. It's the same mapping up to a rotation.

Comment: May I ask you about Q2? I have to proof  "1. it's linear transformation, and  2. it's invertible.(by Det B≠0) " to confirm  it's L.T. How would you proof 1. ?

Comment: Easy: use the definition of linear mapping. If you pose that as its own question I'll answer if I get to it first.