# confirm isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

e.g:

> Let **V** be the span of sin*x* and cos*x* in C∞, T(f)= 3f + 2f'- f'', T: V → V,
>    Is T an isomorphism?

How do I solve this kind of questions?
I know it has to satisfy:
1. Linear Transformation
2. Invertible
But I'm wondering where to start. And I'm really thankful for your help.

Comment: Note: this post is the second (unanswered) part of a [previously asked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804940/arrangement-of-basis).

Comment: $T (f+g)=\dots$ and keep going. Similarly with the scalar multiplication. If $T (f)=T (g)$, then $\dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Just use the definitions. If you want know that T is linear, prove that $T(\alpha f+\beta g)=\alpha T(f)+\beta T(g)$ holds for all $\alpha, \beta \in V$. If you want to know that $T$ is invertible, prove that it is both injective ind surjective. (Note: For the finite dimensional vector space case, it is only necessary to prove one of them)

Besides, as $[ \sin, \cos ]$ is a basis of $V$, for all $f\in V$, suppose f = $a\cos+b\sin$. Then 
$$
\begin{align}
T(f) &= 3f+2f'-f''
   \\&=3(a\cos+b\sin)+2(-a\sin+b\cos)-(-a\cos-b\sin)
   \\&=(4a+2b)\cos+(-2a+4b)\sin
\end{align}
$$
and the coordinate transform is $(a,b)\mapsto(4a+2b, -2a+4b)$. It shouldn't be hard to prove that it is both linear and invertible.

Comment: Exactly from my comment on the previous question.

Comment: Can I suppose f = a sin+b cos?

Comment: @JoyceWang Yes, because your question states that “let V be the span of sinx and cosx”, and f is a vector in V.

Comment: Then, why do you suppose f = acos+bsin ? Is there any reason?